# proper curl command for delete with > one word as the parameter

Tags: java, rest, curl

I have a rest request like the following:

```
@DeleteMapping(value = "v1/delete/{id}")
public void deleteRecord(
        @PathVariable @NotBlank @Parameter(description = "id", required = true) String id) {
    service.deleteRecord(id);
}
```

the id is a String, and can have multiple words with spaces in between like

```
RO RE MI FA SO
```

I would like to construct a curl command that supports String with spaces, but I don't know how. Below does not pick up second word.

```
curl -k -X DELETE https://localhost:8080/v1/delete/DO RI
```

grateful for ideas. Thanks

Comment: Your method is annotated with a `v1/delete` path, but your curl command is using `delete/v1`.

Comment: Have you tried to quote it or urlencode it?

Comment: @VGR sorry, I copy-pasted wrong. The query works fine, it just doesn't read past blank space

Comment: **URL cannot contain space.** [To _represent_ space use %20](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding). PS: using 8080 for https is very confusing and likely to cause mistakes.

Comment: Space characters are not allowed in URLs.  This is not a Java restriction;  it is part of the URI specification.  Characters which cannot appear directly in URIs need to be percent-escaped:  `https://localhost:8080/v1/delete/DO%20RI`

Comment: @VGR, thank you. Thats exactly what the issue was: I needed to URL encode the entire variable. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was provided by VGR. URLs cannot contain spaces, so I simply needed to URL encode the spaces in the parameter:

https://localhost:8080/v1/delete/DO%20RI